# Headphones plugged in causes audio stuttering?

Tags: nvidia, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

Linux noob here. Off a fresh install of 18.04 LTS, plugging in and using headphones causes the audio to stutter intermittently, whether streaming from a browser or playing a file in VLC, etc. I get this bug in both ubuntu and mint installs. Switching to an HDMI output alleviates this issue somewhat(the sound outputs through my monitor); audio plays absolutely fine if headphones aren't plugged in at all. In pavucontrol and the sound settings menu, I can see the headphone going from detected to undetected as stuttering occurs. See [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MyJnmJnj1Qc&feature=youtu.be).

I noticed that pavucontrol frequently attempts to connect to pulseaudio when sound is output through headphones. lspci audio output in terminal specifies:

```
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GK104 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
```

In alsamixer, the display reads:

```
Card: HDA Intel PCH
Chip: Realtek ALC887-VD
```

or

```
Card: HDA NVidia
Chip: NVidia GPU 40 HDMI/DP
```

I've tried removing pulse, switching alsa automute to disabled, using a different gfx driver, editing the pulse config files in several permutations based on related questions, but nothing I've found so far seems to describe my problem or present a solution.

SPECS:
CPU: Intel Core i5-4690k 3500 MHz
Motherboard: ASUS H97-PLUS
BIOS Ver. 0316
Graphics Card: MSI Gaming G Series NVIDIA Geforce GTX 770

Ideally I'd like to stop the stuttering, but if someone can point out which area I should focus my debugging I'd really appreciate it.